# How get child posts in custom post type by ajax?

Tags: ajax, request-filter

I get posts and filter ayahs by tags. I get all the posts. This works well. But when I get to the parent page of the post, I need to get only child posts and filter them. I use 'post_parent' => $ post-> ID in the request, but this does not work in the function. If I use the query on the page where I want to get it, it prints well.

```
/*Ajax Filter*/

//Get Applications Filters
function get_applications_filters()
{
    $args = array( 'taxonomy'      => array( 'products_tags'));
    $terms = get_terms( $args, $deprecated );
    $filters_html = false;

    if( $terms ):
        $filters_html = '<ul>';

        foreach( $terms as $term )
        {
            $term_id = $term->term_id;
            $term_name = $term->name;

            $filters_html .= '<li class="term_id_'.$term_id.'">'.$term_name.'<input type="checkbox" name="filter_applications[]" value="'.$term_id.'"></li>';   
        }
        $filters_html .= '<li class="clear-all">Reset Filter</li>';
        $filters_html .= '</ul>';

        return $filters_html;
    endif;
}

//Add Ajax Actions
add_action('wp_ajax_applications_filter', 'ajax_applications_filter');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_applications_filter', 'ajax_applications_filter');

//Construct Loop & Results
function ajax_applications_filter()
{
    $query_data = $_GET;

    $applications_terms = ($query_data['applications']) ? explode(',',$query_data['applications']) : false;

    $tax_query = ($applications_terms) ? array( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'products_tags',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $applications_terms
    ) ) : false;

    $search_value = ($query_data['search']) ? $query_data['search'] : false;

    //$paged = (isset($query_data['paged']) ) ? intval($query_data['paged']) : 1;

    $products_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'products',
        's' => $search_value,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => $tax_query,
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
        //'paged' => $paged
    );

    $products_loop = new WP_Query($products_args);

    if( $products_loop->have_posts() ):
        while( $products_loop->have_posts() ): $products_loop->the_post();
            get_template_part('template-parts/content-products-archive');
        endwhile;
    else:
        get_template_part('content-none');
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();

    die();
}
```

AJAX

```
//Applications Ajax Filtering
jQuery(function($) {
    //Load posts on page load
    applications_get_posts();

    //If list item is clicked, trigger input change and add css class
    $('#applications-filter li').live('click', function(){
        var input = $(this).find('input');

        if ( $(this).attr('class') == 'clear-all' )
        {
            $('#applications-filter li').removeClass('selected').find('input').prop('checked',false);
            applications_get_posts();
        }
        else if (input.is(':checked'))
        {
            input.prop('checked', false);
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            input.prop('checked', true);
            $(this).addClass('selected');   
        }

        input.trigger("change");


    });

    //If input is changed, load posts
    $('#applications-filter input').live('change', function(){
        applications_get_posts(); //Load Posts
    });


    //Find Selected Applications
    function getSelectedApplications()
    {
        var applications = [];

        $("#applications-filter li input:checked").each(function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            applications.push(val);
        });     

        return applications;
    }

    //Fire ajax request when typing in search
    $('#applications-search input.text-search').live('keyup', function(e){
        if( e.keyCode == 27 )
        {
            $(this).val('');
        }

        applications_get_posts(); //Load Posts
    });

    $('#submit-search').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        applications_get_posts(); //Load Posts
    });

    //Get Search Form Values
    function getSearchValue()
    {
        var searchValue = $('#applications-search input.text-search').val();    
        return searchValue;
    }

    //If pagination is clicked, load correct posts
    $('.applications-filter-navigation a').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var paged = url.split('&paged=');

        applications_get_posts(paged[1]); //Load Posts (feed in paged value)
    });

    //Main ajax function
    function applications_get_posts(paged)
    {
        var paged_value = paged;
        var ajax_url = ajax_applications_params.ajax_url;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'applications_filter',
                applications: getSelectedApplications,
                search: getSearchValue(),
                paged: paged_value
            },
            beforeSend: function ()
            {


            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                //Hide loader here
                $('#applications-results').html(data);
                $('#applications-results .wrap').matchHeight({
                byRow: true
            });
            },
            error: function()
            {
                $("#applications-results").html('<p>There has been an error</p>');
            }
        });             
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the post details you have to send the data yourself.

In your **JavaScript** code you did not send **post id**.

Update your code like this:

```
data:{
    action: "applications_filter",
    post_id: current_post_id, //current_post_id should either parsed from DOM or you can write your ajax in PHP file
}
```

You must need to send **post_id** before using in php file.

Then you can retrieve via GET

```
function ajax_applications_filter(){
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

    //Now set post_parent, it will be work
    $products_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'products',
        's' => $search_value,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => $tax_query,
        'post_parent' => $post_id
        //'paged' => $paged
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!

data:{
    action: "applications_filter",
    post_id: current_post_id, 
}

In this code dont work, becouse  current_post_id is not defined